# Updating a class variable also influences already created objects

Tags: python, oop

I have the following code:

```
class ExampleClass:
    varia = 1
    def __init__(self, val, valentered):
        ExampleClass.varia = val
        self.val2=valentered


print(ExampleClass.__dict__)

class_1=ExampleClass(4,"A")

print(ExampleClass.__dict__)

class_2=ExampleClass(3,"B")

print(ExampleClass.__dict__)

print(class_1.varia)
print(class_2.varia)

print(class_1.val2)
print(class_2.val2)
```

That means I have a class ExampleClass from which I create the objects class_1 and class_2. I understand that with the `__init__` each time I create an object from the class that I modify the class variable varia. So I understand that this changes from 1 to 4 and then to 3. However, I would have expected that the class_1 still has object variable with value 4 and not 3. The output is:

```
{'__module__': '__main__', 'varia': 1, '__init__': <function ExampleClass.__init__ at 0x000001A7A02C6EE8>, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'ExampleClass' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'ExampleClass' objects>, '__doc__': None}
{'__module__': '__main__', 'varia': 4, '__init__': <function ExampleClass.__init__ at 0x000001A7A02C6EE8>, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'ExampleClass' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'ExampleClass' objects>, '__doc__': None}
{'__module__': '__main__', 'varia': 3, '__init__': <function ExampleClass.__init__ at 0x000001A7A02C6EE8>, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'ExampleClass' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'ExampleClass' objects>, '__doc__': None}
3
3
A
B
```

So

```
print(class_1.varia)
print(class_2.varia)
```

gives

```
3
3
```

I thought that when I create an object from a class that this object inherits the class variables (varia) and get's assigned specific instance variables (val2) which can differ for each instance, while the class variable is the same for all objects from this class.

So for me the object was created and then exists. It inherits, but there is no connection back and especially no automatically updating. If I wanted to change the specific attributes (instance and also object attributes) of this object I have to explicitely modify this specific object. It does not help me to change the class object in general, as the object is not explicitly created again. But I see that I am wrong. When I run the `class_2=ExampleClass(3,"B")` the varia of class_1 is also changed to 3 from previously 4. Why is this the case? When a child is born it is born once. The inheritance happens once. Why should then changing the parent influence the child, if I not explicitly create the child again or update the child?

I thought that when I create an object and then another these inherit specific values from a class. But these are two different existing objects. So their object values can differ and do not have to be the same.

Or is it that I have to imagine it as one large bubble (class) where smaller bubbles exist which can have different attributes (instance), but they are always inside this larger bubble and can't get out of it, so their class variables are the same. But that would mean that there cannot be any objects from the same class with different object variables/attributes (althought the class variable itself can be changed, but then for all objects from/in this class) and I think this is wrong.

To illustrate my problem one could also reduce it by removing the instance attributes:

```
class ExampleClass:
    varia = 1
#    def __init__(self, val, valentered):
#        ExampleClass.varia = val
#        self.val2=valentered

class_1=ExampleClass()

ExampleClass.varia=2

class_2=ExampleClass()

print(class_1.varia)
print(class_2.varia)
```

which gives

```
2
2
```

and I expected

```
1
2
```

Comment: The rules for this are fairly simple.  When you create a new instance of a class, and it doesn't set `self.var`, then it will access `var` from the class itself.  If the class value of `var` changes, the instance will pick up the latest value, i.e. it will change.  If you want to freeze the value at the time the instance is created, just add the following to the `__init__` method:  `self.var = self.var`.  This will access the class value of `var`, and store it in the instance.  From then on, the instance will have its own `var` which is decoupled from the class value.

Comment: Because varia is a class variable and all objects of that class share this variable, you have to use instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

In Python everything is an object.
Instances are object, naturally.
But Classes are objects too, which may not seem obvious at first.
The difference between classes and instances is actually purely semantic, and conventional (instances names are *snake_case* while classes names are *CamelCase) but not technical.
That's the reason why you can call `__dict__` on instances **and** classes, because both are objects.
Taking a look at the [Python Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) may be interesting.
A class just acts as a template to create instances, it is an object to create other similar objects.

You were not surprised that `class_1.val2` and `class_2.val2` were different, because they are two different objects with each a `val2` member variable.
But there is only one `ExampleClass` which has a `.varia` member variable. Why would it not change ?
I think you were confused by what is **actually** inheritance.

> I thought that when I create an object from a class that this object inherits the class variables (varia) [...], while the class variable is the same for all objects from this class.

You do not inherit class variables. A "class variable" would be more correctly named "a regular member variable of an instance (but the instance is a class)". With no instances, it would work exactly the same :

```py
class Foo:
    classvar = 0


def just_a_regular_function():
    Foo.classvar += 1
    print(f"classvar={Foo.classvar}")


just_a_regular_function()  # classvar=1
just_a_regular_function()  # classvar=2
just_a_regular_function()  # classvar=3
just_a_regular_function()  # classvar=4
```

You are just modifying the member variable of an instance (which is a class, but that changes nothing).

See also : [Python doc about classes, section on class variables](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables)